# SLDS Source Code

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, slds

I want to download the whole SLDS and inspect the CSS code on which it is based.

For example:

```
<div class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="height:5rem">This content will be positioned in the absolute center of its container</div>
```

I want to inspect the slds-align_absolute-center class.

There is a [GIT repository](https://github.com/salesforce-ux/design-system) which I cloned and started on my localhost using NPM based on the repository instructions. To my suprise there is no source CSS code.

Is there a way to get the CSS classes so I can inspect them? I need to prepare myself for coding some LWC components and I want to make sure that in case the client will require a complex solution beyond the SLDS library, I'll be able to take the raw CSS and adjust it according to the client's requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You can download it as a .zip file [here](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/resources/downloads/).

Answer (score 1):

You can see it under [ui/utilities/alignment/_index.scss](https://github.com/salesforce-ux/design-system/blob/main/ui/utilities/alignment/_index.scss). It just uses [absolute-center](https://github.com/salesforce-ux/design-system/blob/main/ui/dependencies/_layout.scss) which you can see under `ui/dependencies/_layout.scss`.

```css
/**
 * @summary Class will absolutely center children content
 *
 * @name absolute-center
 * @selector .slds-align_absolute-center
 * @modifier
 */
.slds-align_absolute-center,
.slds-align--absolute-center {
  @include absolute-center;
}
```

In that directory ([ui](https://github.com/salesforce-ux/design-system/tree/main/ui)), you should see various categories. If you wanted to search in VS Code:

- Search: slds class (ex. `.slds-align_absolute-center`)
- Files to include: `.scss`

Comment: Thanks. Edited my answer to provide examples to the solution.

Comment: FYI - you also can answer your own question (and accept it). You ended up editing your _question_ with an _answer_ while this site has a specific mechanism/separation for answers

Comment: Aha, okay. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. SLDS uses [@mixin and @include annotations](https://www.w3schools.com/sass/sass_mixin_include.php).

> The @mixin directive lets you create CSS code that is to be reused
> throughout the website.
>
> The @include directive is created to let you use (include) the mixin.

I got confused by this line in the SLDS repo:

```css
.slds-align_absolute-center,
.slds-align--absolute-center {
    @include absolute-center;
}
```

I figured out that the actual code is in the ui/dependencies folder:

```css
@mixin absolute-center {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: auto;
}
```